# Oyster card broken - can I get a refund?

Tags: public-transport, tickets, london, tfl, oyster-card

My Oyster card has physically broken (it's bent and no longer reads). The ticket office advised me to buy a new one and phone the support line to get the credit transferred, but can I also get the £5 deposit refunded?

Comment: You'd normally only get a "deposit" back if you returned the item (undamaged). So probably not.

Comment: In the end, TfL did in fact refund my deposit and send me a new Oyster card.

Answer (score 14):

[The TfL website does not mention a deposit refund for faulty Oyster cards.](https://tfl.gov.uk/fares-and-payments/replacements-and-refunds/oyster-refunds-and-replacements#on-this-page-1) They only mention that after you get a new card they will transfer the credit and passes you had on the faulty card. Quoting from TfL:

> ### Faulty Oyster card
>
> If your Oyster card doesn't work when you touch it on a yellow card reader, it may be faulty.
>
> You'll need to get a new Oyster card and add some pay as you go credit. Staff at a Tube station may be able to issue the new card for you with some credit on it.
>
> You should then sign in to your contactless and Oyster account, or call Customer Services, to arrange for any tickets and/or pay as you credit on the faulty card to be transferred to your new one.
>
> If you had a discount on your faulty Oyster card, you will need to take it to a Tube station to get it reset. If necessary, remember to take your discount photocard with you.

It would seem that you can get a refund for the deposit only if you return an unneeded Oyster card:

> ### No longer need your Oyster card?
>
> If you no longer need your Oyster card, you can get a refund for:
>
> - Any unused pay as you go credit
> - The remaining value of any Travelcard or Bus & Tram Pass season ticket
> - Your deposit

If I were you I would contact TfL and ask them directly about the deposit refund for a faulty card.

Comment: Thanks for this - Re `If I were you I would contact TfL and ask them directly about the deposit refund for a faulty card.`, this is the plan, but I'm hoping to get some information on my side first ;)

Comment: @Eoin, no need for thanks, but please read http://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers

Comment: They just give you a new card so I assume that when you return *that* you get the deposit but don't know for sure.